# Scroll down animation is not as smooth as expected?

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation

I have a problem with the scroll down effect I am trying to use. Currently it is using the jQuery **animate** method. For some reason it shows some flickering while scroll down automatically?

Is there a way to avoid this or a solution to overcome this?

Please see below my code. Any advice is really appreciated!

```js
$(function() {
  $('a[href*=#]').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $($(this).attr('href')).offset().top
    }, 500, 'linear');
  });
});
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Josefin+Sans:300,400);
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

section {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

section::after {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  height: 80%;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0, rgba(0, 0, 0, .8) 80%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .8) 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0, rgba(0, 0, 0, .8) 80%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .8) 100%);
}

section h1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  z-index: 2;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  color: #fff;
  font: normal 300 64px/1 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

#section01 {
  background: url(https://picsum.photos/1200/800?image=575) center center / cover no-repeat;
}

#section02 {
  background: url(https://picsum.photos/1200/800?image=1016) center center / cover no-repeat;
}

#section03 {
  background: url(https://picsum.photos/1200/800?image=869) center center / cover no-repeat;
}

#section04 {
  background: url(https://picsum.photos/1200/800?image=506) center center / cover no-repeat;
}

#section05 {
  background: url(https://picsum.photos/1200/800?image=1037) center center / cover no-repeat;
}

#section06 {
  background: url(https://picsum.photos/1200/800?image=901) center center / cover no-repeat;
}

#section07 {
  background: url(https://picsum.photos/1200/800?image=675) center center / cover no-repeat;
}

#section08 {
  background: url(https://picsum.photos/1200/800?image=1050) center center / cover no-repeat;
}

#section09 {
  background: url(https://picsum.photos/1200/800?image=902) center center / cover no-repeat;
}

#section10 {
  background: url(https://picsum.photos/1200/800?image=516) center center / cover no-repeat;
}

#thanks {
  background-color: #fff;
}

#thanks::after {
  content: none;
}

#thanks div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  z-index: 2;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
}

#thanks h2 {
  margin-bottom: 60px;
  color: #333;
  font: normal 300 64px/1 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

#thanks p {
  color: #333;
  font: normal 400 20px/1 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
}

#thanks p a {
  color: #333;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: color .3s;
}

#thanks p a:hover {
  color: #888;
}

.demo a {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20px;
  left: 50%;
  z-index: 2;
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, -50%);
  transform: translate(0, -50%);
  color: #fff;
  font: normal 400 20px/1 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: .1em;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: opacity .3s;
}

.demo a:hover {
  opacity: .5;
}

#section01 a {
  padding-top: 60px;
}

#section01 a span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  margin-left: -12px;
  border-left: 1px solid #fff;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#section02 a {
  padding-top: 60px;
}

#section02 a span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  width: 46px;
  height: 46px;
  margin-left: -23px;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#section02 a span::after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  content: '';
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  margin: -12px 0 0 -8px;
  border-left: 1px solid #fff;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#section03 a {
  padding-top: 60px;
}

#section03 a span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  width: 46px;
  height: 46px;
  margin-left: -23px;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#section03 a span::after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  content: '';
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  margin: -12px 0 0 -8px;
  border-left: 1px solid #fff;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#section03 a span::before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  content: '';
  width: 44px;
  height: 44px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, .1);
  border-radius: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-animation: sdb03 3s infinite;
  animation: sdb03 3s infinite;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

@-webkit-keyframes sdb03 {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  30% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  60% {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 60px rgba(255, 255, 255, .1);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes sdb03 {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  30% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  60% {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 60px rgba(255, 255, 255, .1);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

#section04 a {
  padding-top: 60px;
}

#section04 a span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  margin-left: -12px;
  border-left: 1px solid #fff;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -webkit-animation: sdb04 2s infinite;
  animation: sdb04 2s infinite;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

@-webkit-keyframes sdb04 {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(0, 0);
  }
  20% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-10px, 10px);
  }
  40% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(0, 0);
  }
}

@keyframes sdb04 {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(0, 0);
  }
  20% {
    transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-10px, 10px);
  }
  40% {
    transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(0, 0);
  }
}

#section05 a {
  padding-top: 70px;
}

#section05 a span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  margin-left: -12px;
  border-left: 1px solid #fff;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -webkit-animation: sdb05 1.5s infinite;
  animation: sdb05 1.5s infinite;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

@-webkit-keyframes sdb05 {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(0, 0);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-20px, 20px);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes sdb05 {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(0, 0);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-20px, 20px);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

#section06 a {
  padding-top: 70px;
}

#section06 a span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  margin-left: -12px;
  border-left: 1px solid #fff;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
  -webkit-transform: rotateZ(-45deg);
  transform: rotateZ(-45deg);
  -webkit-animation: sdb06 1.5s infinite;
  animation: sdb06 1.5s infinite;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

@-webkit-keyframes sdb06 {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(0) rotateZ(-45deg) translate(0, 0);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(720deg) rotateZ(-45deg) translate(-20px, 20px);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes sdb06 {
  0% {
    transform: rotateY(0) rotateZ(-45deg) translate(0, 0);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotateY(720deg) rotateZ(-45deg) translate(-20px, 20px);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

#section07 a {
  padding-top: 80px;
}

#section07 a span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  margin-left: -12px;
  border-left: 1px solid #fff;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -webkit-animation: sdb07 2s infinite;
  animation: sdb07 2s infinite;
  opacity: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#section07 a span:nth-of-type(1) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0s;
  animation-delay: 0s;
}

#section07 a span:nth-of-type(2) {
  top: 16px;
  -webkit-animation-delay: .15s;
  animation-delay: .15s;
}

#section07 a span:nth-of-type(3) {
  top: 32px;
  -webkit-animation-delay: .3s;
  animation-delay: .3s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes sdb07 {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes sdb07 {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

#section08 a {
  padding-top: 60px;
}

#section08 a span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  width: 30px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-left: -15px;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 50px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#section08 a span::before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 50%;
  content: '';
  width: 6px;
  height: 6px;
  margin-left: -3px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#section09 a {
  padding-top: 80px;
}

#section09 a span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  width: 30px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-left: -15px;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 50px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#section09 a span::before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 50%;
  content: '';
  width: 6px;
  height: 6px;
  margin-left: -3px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#section09 a span::after {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -18px;
  left: 50%;
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  content: '';
  margin-left: -9px;
  border-left: 1px solid #fff;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#section10 a {
  padding-top: 60px;
}

#section10 a span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  width: 30px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-left: -15px;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 50px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#section10 a span::before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 50%;
  content: '';
  width: 6px;
  height: 6px;
  margin-left: -3px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 100%;
  -webkit-animation: sdb10 2s infinite;
  animation: sdb10 2s infinite;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

@-webkit-keyframes sdb10 {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  40% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  80% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, 20px);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes sdb10 {
  0% {
    transform: translate(0, 0);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  40% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  80% {
    transform: translate(0, 20px);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<section id="section09" class="demo">
  <h1>Scroll Down Button #9</h1>
  <a href="#section10"><span></span>Scroll</a>
</section>
<section id="section10" class="demo">
  <h1>Scroll Down Button #10</h1>
  <a href="#thanks"><span></span>Scroll</a>
</section>
<section id="thanks">
  <div>
    <h2>Thanks!</h2>
    <p><a href="https://www.nxworld.net/tips/css-scroll-down-button.html" target="_parent">&lt; Back To Article</a></p>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: My sample -  https://codepen.io/Kumaresan_sd/pen/PMQLgY

Comment: @jakeLovelock, i need suggestions not editing?

Comment: I'm editing it so people can understand what your issue is and this will help people to come up with answers. I think what you're looking for is "Thank you."